# mapping column names in sas

Tags: sas, compare

I have two tables in SAS

I need to compare the both tables

If the column  data is same

then map the column names table1. employee (map) table2.employee

because data is same in both of them

how can I implement this in SAS ?

Comment: Are you implying that the variable names are different but the values will be the same so you want to map them somehow? This would be a data intensive effort, how big is your data and what number of columns are you looking at. Please post some sample data and what you expect as output.

Comment: Yes.Its a large data set having 220 columns and 65 million records.                               ex: table1 column{network : 'USA','BRAVO',etc..}                                                         table 2 column{net : 'USA','BRAVO',etc..}                                                            now values are same in both the columns .So map {network : net}

Comment: Can you use a sample instead of all the rows? 220 columns, choose 2, is 24k comparisons *65 million if you want to check all values. You don't have any documentation on a dataset that big?

Answer (score 0):

PROC COMPARE.

The COMPARE procedure compares the contents of two SAS data sets, selected variables in different data sets, or variables within the same data set.
PROC COMPARE compares two data sets: the base data set and the comparison data set. The procedure determines matching variables and matching observations. Matching variables are variables with the same name or variables that you pair by using the VAR and WITH statements. Matching variables must be of the same type. Matching observations are observations that have the same values for all ID variables that you specify or, if you do not use the ID statement, that occur in the same position in the data sets. If you match observations by ID variables, then both data sets must be sorted by all ID variables.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#compare-overview.htm